# Field names are zzktl, zzktm, zzktn in Watches

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am trying to test [this sample code](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reading-qr-codes-using-the-mobile-vision-api--cms-24680) which uses Google's Vision API. In `receiveDetections`, I tried to view what fields the argument has. The problem is that field names are cryptic. Why are the field names cryptic?

[image]

```
dependencies {
   ....
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.6.0'
}
```

Comment: That's proguard, obfuscates the google play library too. Check if it is enabled in build.gradle

Comment: The only thing I could find was the auto-generated thing, `release{proguardFiles...}`. But my build type is `Debug`. Anyways, I commented out the proguardFiles line, but the field names were the same.